# Validating a custom php fucntion, inside of a gravity form

Tags: php, html, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am currently making a type of calculator for a client at the company I work for inside of gravity forms in WordPress.

The basis of the calculator is, you can choose a language you want to translate English to, e.g English to Spanish, English to Italian, English to German etc. The languages you can choose are in a multiple option field in GF, and each language has a different value such as Spanish = 10, Greek = 50, German = 25 etc, the number are currency and you can choose how many words you want to translate, and it is in between 100 to 600.

The 'Word Count' field basically rounds up numbers, so if somebody want's 100 words writing, that will be £40, if they want 551 words, that would be £75.

The issue I am having is, the gform_field_validation doesn't do anything, well, it doesn't seem to validate my field / function at all. I have followed the gravity forms documentation and have implemented the form ID and field ID, I have used the Gravity forms debugging tool, such as GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform custom logging'); to see if it is in the log when you submit the form, but nothing, it doesn't pull my function in.

See below my php and HTML:

```
    add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_45_8', 'custom_validation', 10, 4 );
function custom_validation( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug( 'gform custom logging');
    if ( $result['is_valid'] && intval( $value ) < 10 ) {
        $result['is_valid'] = false;
        $result['message'] = 'Please enter a value between 100 and 600.';
    }
    return $result;
}

function wordCalculator($word_count) {
        $minimum_charge = 40;

        if ($word_count >= 100 && $word_count <= 300) {
            $output = 40;
        } else if ($word_count >= 301 && $word_count <= 350) {
            $output = 43.75;
        } else if ($word_count >= 351 && $word_count <= 400) {
            $output = 50;
        } else if ($word_count >= 401 && $word_count <= 450) {
            $output = 56.25;
        } else if ($word_count >= 451 && $word_count <= 500) {
            $output = 62.50;
        } else if ($word_count >= 501 && $word_count <= 550) {
            $output = 68.75;
        } else if ($word_count >= 551 && $word_count <= 600) {
            $output = 75;
        } else {
            $output = "Please enter a value between 100 and 600.";
        }
        if ($output < $minimum_charge) {
            $output = $minimum_charge;
        }

        return $output;
    };
```

HTML

```
<label name="word-count-label">Word Count</label><br>
<input type="text" for="word_count" id="word_count"><br>
<input type="submit">
```

Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated as I'm still in the teething phase of my php journey and an little in the deep here, thanks guys.

Comment: Where did you put the PHP code?

Comment: I put it inside of my functions.php file

Comment: And you're sure the form and field ID used in the hook are correct? What happens when you just use the general `gform_field_validation` filter, do you get to see any debug log entries then?

Comment: Yeah so the form is 8, and my field is 45 for the Word Count, i have tried to swap these values around to see if I had put them in wrong but that doesn't seem to make a difference, I'll get a debug log now.

Comment: @CBroe here is the log in the debug, it seems to now pickup my debug line. 2023-06-27 8:57:17.086792 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::validate(): Starting for form #8. 
2023-06-27 8:57:17.086811 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::validate(): Executing functions hooked to gform_pre_validation. 
2023-06-27 8:57:17.093961 - DEBUG --> GFFormDisplay::validate(): Completed gform_pre_validation.